# input output dimension in keras dense layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a dense layer in keras. The input is EEG recording using 2 channels, each of them consist of a vector of 8 points and the total number of training points is 17. The `y` is also 17 points.

I used

```
x=x.reshape(17,2,8,1)
y=y.reshape(17,1,1,1)

model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,8,1), activation='relu'))
print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
print(model.compile)

model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 17,epochs=500, verbose=1)
```

but i get the following error

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_57 to have shape (2, 8, 1) but got array with shape (17, 1, 1)
```

Comment: can you show the `model.fit` code as well?

Comment: model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam') model.fit(X_mkr3, y_mkr3, batch_size = 17,epochs=500, verbose=1)

Comment: can you try naming the parameters like `model.fit(x=X_mkr3, ...)`?

Comment: the first dimension is for batch, it can't be different.

Comment: i mean in the last line of the code instead of `model.fit(x, y, ...)` do `model.fit(x=x, y=y, ...)`

Comment: yes i tried, i got the same result

Comment: also in the `y` you need to have `17` as the first dimension. `y = y.reshape(17, 1, 1, 1) `

Comment: now i get ...Error when checking target: expected dense_61 to have shape (2, 8, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1, 1)

Comment: that is because the output dimension of the layer doesn't match with dimension of `y`

Comment: so how should i fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212932/discussion-between-learner-and-user3729332).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `Dense` layer has output dimension `1`, it would expect `y` to be of the shape `(2, 8, 1)`. An easy fix would be to do the following

```
x = x.reshape(17, 16)
y = y.reshape(17, 1)

model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(16,), activation='relu'))
```

Comment: @user3729332 that is great, to mark an answer accepted, please click the grey tick mark beside the answer